# How do I move a btrfs subvolume and its snapshots to another drive?

Tags: btrfs

How do I move a btrfs subvolume and its snapshots to another drive? Based on my understanding of the btrfs-send man page I think I would have to manually reconstruct the child/parent relationships using the -p flag and multiple invocations of btrfs-send. Is there an easier way?

Note that there is question similar to this one that asks about volumes. I'm asking here about a subvolume.